# How to overcome os not being found after installation

Tags: boot, lubuntu

I installed lubuntu 12.04 on IBM Thinkpad R50 without any other OS.  At end of installation I restarted as instructed but had error OS not found.  Have repeated installation with both DVD and USB stick but same result. Parted, used via trial version after installation, seems to show boot partition exists.  Obviously with only trial version, can't make any changes to HDD. I should mention that I am installing 12.04 because of PAE problem with intention to update to 16.04.  I am also an Ubuntu beginner.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like during installation, the GRUB bootloader didn't get installed to the correct drive/partition, and the BIOS is looking in the wrong spot. When you install Ubuntu, it will ask you where you want the GRUB bootloader to be installed. Take a look at the dropdown menu that's given, and make sure it's installing to your primary hard disk (for example `/dev/sda` or `/dev/hda`; it may or may not have a partition number afterwards).

Additionally, check your boot order in your BIOS settings. Not having a ThinkPad in front of me I can't be sure, but some BIOSes will give the boot order as something like "Hard drive, network, optical drive, USB device" and from within hard drive, for example, it will let you pick which partition is the one you want to boot from. Other BIOSes will present each boot option on it's own, for example if you have two USB drives plugged in, they will each be presented as a boot option and you can select which one you want to try first.

You might want to try installing a later version of Ubuntu, upgrading from 12.04 to 16.04 will be a bit tricky as the older versions have been deprecated, and you don't want to try to upgrade directly from 12.04 to 16.04. For a machine of that age, Xubuntu or Lubuntu are good choices. If you're having issues with PAE, try a non-PAE 32 bit version; unless you've got 4GB of RAM in it I would not bother with the PAE version.

Have you tried a minimal installer? [Try this one for 16.04 LTS](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/mini.iso). You'll need a network connection during install; just select Lxde or Xfce for the desktop environment if you need a GUI. **This might be a wise choice, since you mentioned using 12.04 due to a PAE error**

Comment: I updated my answer to hopefully provide more information. The reason I suggested the alternate installer is due to the OP's statement that they were using 12.04 due to a PAE problem.

Comment: hmm actually I should stop reviewing and go to bed since I misunderstood part of your answer on first read - sorry! Looks better now (not sure boot order is relevant - usually something boots if anything can in my experience, but *shrug*) I will check back later and see if OP has any luck with your answer since I don't know the hardware/PAE issues well enough to be able to upvote it in good conscience as is. Thanks a lot for contributing :)

Comment: Was boot problem.  Thinkpad BIOS was excluding HDD from boot order despite being set to boot from HDD.  V14.04 needs PAE and can't upgrade from V12.04 for same reason as Thinkpad doesn't have pae and can't be forced according to reports.